# accessing program listing in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm having some strange (or not so strange) problems defining variables in SWI-Prolog. Example:

I'd like to do something like below:

```
:- initialization(main).

main :- 
X = listing(main),
write(X).
```

but it's simply printing "listing(main)"

Comment: need a screenshot? edit: oh, i forgot to add the write(X). :p

Comment: main :- X = listing(main). <- that's just cheating to make a quine, what i want to do is store the result in to a variable to use it later.

Comment: See [this quine](http://www.logic.at/prolog/various/quine.pl).

Comment: that's cool, but doesn't help me.. just need to store the result of the code listing(main) in to the variable X. now X contains the output.

Comment: I still fail to understand what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe, using another casual predicate instead of main/0...

```
?- with_output_to(atom(X), listing(pattern)), write(X).
gram:pattern(A, B, C) :-
    dig(A, B, C).
gram:pattern(A+C, B, E) :-
    ten(A, B, D),
    dig(C, D, E).
...
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing with `X = listing(...)` is creating a **term**, which later you are printing with write.

It seems you want to access the code of main. The thing you are looking for is [`clause/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=clause/2):

> **clause(:Head, ?Body)**
>
> True if Head can be unified with a clause head and Body with the corresponding clause body. Gives alternative clauses on backtracking. For facts, Body is unified with the atom true.

Example:

```
main :- clause(main, X), write(X).

?- main.
clause(main,_G2381),write(_G2381)
true.
```